# Google cloud service account is being denied permission to push to Artifact Registry from azure pipeline

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops

While trying publish docker image from azure pipeline with gcp service account to artifact registry getting below error. Service account has below properties

1. Artifact Registry Administrator
2. Artifact Registry Writer
3. Editor

```
denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to push the spring boot docker image from azure pipeline to gcp artifact registry by providing the path as project-name/folder-name/image-name in container repository in docker task of azure pipeline.
With that I had configured the connector in azure pipeline by creating new service connector with service account created in gcp